# Wait for certain data from an eventhandler

Tags: c#, event-handling, redirectstandardoutput

I am calling an external executable and reading asynchronously from its standard output stream. I need to wait for some data be passed from the stream.

The simple solution is to use an synchronization flag, use lock to access it, and put a infinite cycle that breaks out when the flag is set. 
Is there a more elegant, safe way, to do this?

Here is what i am trying to accomplish:

```
bool sync = false;
Object thisLock = new Object();

MyExec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
MyExec.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
MyExec.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
            (s, e) =>
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data) || e.Data.Contains('X')
                    lock (thisLock)
                    {
                        sync = true;
                    }
            });
...
while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (sync) break;
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class like this:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

MyExec.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
        (s, e) =>
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data) || e.Data.Contains('X'))
                mre.Set();
        });

...
//On the other thread

//This will wait until the ManualResetEvent is signaled via mre.Set();
mre.WaitOne();
```